# cakephp 3 save data to database dont work after adding new column

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.x

Hey i want to save data to my database with cakephp 3.8. All works but i added a new field "created_by" and changed it in the models folder.

this is my RequestTable.php

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){
    .... (more, but not important)
    $validator
      ->scalar('created_by')
      ->maxLength('created_by', 100)
      ->allowEmptyString('created_by');

    return $validator;
}
```

My entity file "Request.php"

in the top

```
* @property string|null $created_by
```

and

```
protected $_accessible = [
  ... (more)
  'created_by' => true,
];
```

My code where i want to save the data:

```
$request = $this->Requests->newEntity();
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
if(!empty($session->read('Auth.User.username'))){
  $this->request->data['Requests']['created_by'] = $session->read('Auth.User.username');
}

$request = $this->Requests->patchEntity($request, $this->request->getData('Requests'));
if ($result = $this->Requests->save($request)) {
  ...
}
```

At the empty check it goes in the clause. After the patchEntity the result is the correct data. The same in the save.

The column in the table looks like
`created_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL

I dont know why it doesnt save the data. If someone have more questions about the code please ask :)

Comment: "Dont work" does not sound like you've checked for errors, or did you?

Comment: yes i checked for some errors but there are no ones :/

Comment: Did you clear your ORM cache after adding the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, but if I create a new database with the same schema it works. Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Without an error message. It would be hard to determine where is the flaw. One thing you might consider is checking the database if it is busy handling another process. If there are flood requests that makes your request locked.

Comment: the problem is i dont get an error and the database is not busy :/